# Can't set up environment path variables in new Kali Linux 2021.2 installation

Tags: linux, kali-linux, path

I want to add environment path variable for some stuff as I did in kali linux 2019, but it's not working.  In kali 2019 i put this: `PATH=$PATH:/home/kali/hacking/recon/` in `~/.bashrc` and evertything was fine.

In 2021.2 I have tried to put this in: `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/kali/hacking/recon/
PATH=$PATH:/home/kali/hacking/recon/
```

and it's not working.
`echo $PATH` does not show these paths. Any ideas?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` please

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show? Have you tried `.bash_profile` (if your shell is indeed Bash)?